# Windows 7 Change Power Settings Via CMD Line

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I want to change some of the settings via the command line.

i found this resource which helps
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940(v=ws.10).aspx

but it doesn't explain how to set a time limit to never.

for example i put
   `powercfg -change -disk-timeout-ac never`

and got "The value specified is mal-formed, or is not within the range of the target power setting"

What do i have to put to get the never setting i want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try typing and running the command like this: `powercfg/change disk-timeout-ac 0`